# Docker container with it's own disk and memory

Tags: docker, minikube, docker-container

I wanted to test my app inside docker container for the case when disk is 100% full, or when all system file-descriptors are used, or when memory is used 100% etc...

Is it possible to do this inside docker container? So far I can see that when 'df' command is executed, it shows size of the host system and not docker container one.

I just wanted to specify e.g. 1GB HDD and 1GB RAM, and then use some app to fill the disk and memory for testing.

Comment: Use a headless virtual machine ?

Comment: Yes. this is what I do now. Just wanted to see if possible to limit visible hdd to an app inside docker container, sice this would be easier for me.

Comment: On docker desktop I remember that you can define how much resources to share with containers. Have you tried that way? If you don't have docker desktop describe which OS you have.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

#### Create Volume

---

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=tmpfs \
    --opt device=tmpfs \
    --opt o=size=1g,uid=1000 \
    my-new-volume
```

#### Run Container with new Volume

---

```
docker run -d -v my-new-volume:/in-container-location container-image
```

Have your app write to `/in-container-location`

---

Source - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#examples

#### Memory

---

```
docker run -d --memory="1g" container-image
```

source - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory

#### Mix the two

---

```
docker run -d --memory="1g" -v my-new-volume:/in-container-location container-image
```

Comment: I guess this is my problem: https://ops.tips/blog/why-top-inside-container-wrong-memory/

Comment: In real world use, you should have some sort of data volume if your application needs to write data to disk. This protects your root storage from filling up and then a bunch of other problems can arise at that point.

Comment: You tagged kubernetes in your question too:

Specifying memory limits on your pods is also important for Quality of Service. For example scheduling pods on the right worker nodes and guaranteeing your app has the memory it asks for. In the end your app will run better and you will better utilize your worker nodes resources.